# does pre-sorting a partition tables by certain columns reduce memory used for group bys?

Tags: google-bigquery

assuming we have a table

`CREATE TABLE`dataset.user_activity_log
`(
  partition_time    DATE
  , user_id STRING
  , description STRING
  , activity_id int64
)
PARTITION BY partition_time
OPTIONS(
  description="partitioned by partition_time"
)
;`

And I set it up so that i insert data to it daily and while doing so,
have it order by activity id.

Later on, I would like to create a report over a range of time based on the `partition_time` field, and do a group by on activity id, would having the activity_id field sorted help with (potentially not running out of memory)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called ["Clustered Tables"](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables) and [creating using DDL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#creating_a_clustered_table)

snippet

```
PARTITION BY partition_time
 CLUSTER BY
   activity_id
 OPTIONS (
```

read this as well: [Optimizing BigQuery: Cluster your tables](https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b)

You need to cluster your table further by activity_id. If you got into a memory error post your schema, table size, query, and query plan in a new question and you will get optimization tips.